# SyntaxError: Unexpected token in $http.get() request

Tags: angularjs, json, syntax-error

I tried to make my first Angular app, but faced this error

JS code:

```
var app = angular.module('sortApp', [])
    app.controller('sortController', ['$http', function ($http) {
      var sort = this;
      sort.orders = [];
      $http.get('angular/orders.json').success(function (data) {
        sort.orders = data;
      });
```

Error log:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token n in JSON at position 17
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at cc (angular.js:1139)
    at Ud.e.defaults.transformResponse (angular.js:7481)
    at angular.js:7429
    at r (angular.js:325)
    at xc (angular.js:7428)
    at b (angular.js:8122)
    at L (angular.js:11561)
    at angular.js:11647
    at k.$eval (angular.js:12673)
```

what could cause it?

Comment: validate your JSON, make sure every key is a **strings** . `{n:10}` is not valid, `{"n":10}` is valid

Answer (score -3):

your json is invalid format. Check it first.

Comment: instead of just down vote, please tell something useful. Thank you.